# BufferedReader unexpected behavior

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have an unusual problem with BufferedReader in Java 11. I have a simple command-line student tracker application, that reads input from `System.in`, transforms it into the appropriate implementation of `Command` interface, and executes it.

```
void execute() {
    System.out.println("Learning Progress Tracker");
    try (reader) { // reader is new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
        String line;
        while (!shutdown) {
            line = reader.readLine();
            Command command = Command.stringToCommand(line);
            if (command instanceof ExitCommand) {
                shutdown = true;
            }
            command.execute(reader, db);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Some commands simply process the input and print the output to `System.out`, some keep using `reader` to receive additional input. For example, `AddStudentsCommand` implements execution like so:

```
 public void execute(BufferedReader reader, Database db) {
        String line;
        String[] credentials;
        int numAdded = 0;
        prompt(); // Prints prompt to System.in to enter credentials
        try {
            while (!(line = reader.readLine()).equals("back")) {

                // process input

            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the weird part. After `while (!(line = reader.readLine()).equals("back")) {` line evaluates to true, `reader`'s buffer ends up with leading `\n` in its buffer, followed by whatever I typed, which causes to `readLine()` to fire up twice. And even weirder, that only happens if I comment out `prompt()` (a simple `System.out.println()`) prior to `readLine()`. If some text gets printed to `System.out` before reading, the buffer behaves correctly and leading `\n` doesn't show up. I have recorded a small video to show what I mean: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H7PBr6Qpykg.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and can't understand where that nasty bug is coming from. Can anyone reproduce?

Comment: What version of IntelliJ IDEA are you using?

Comment: @k314159 this is IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 Edu version, I'm doing a Hyperskill project.

Comment: @akarnokd That leading newline char becomes an empty string causing empty credentials to be processed. Then immediately after that actual credentials get processed because it sees a trailing newline and readLine() eats it up following the logic that I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue only occurs when you run your program in the IDE. If you run it from the command line, using the command `java [ClassName]`, it should work just fine.

The problem is a [bug in IntelliJ IDEA](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293951) which was fixed in version 2022.1.2, so you might want to upgrade.

Comment: Yikes. EDU version doesn't have that upgrade. Just tried to run it from the command line and it works perfectly. I thought I was losing it, glad to know that it is indeed a bug. :-) Thanks!